# enlarging a thumbnail onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a sort of image library where the user can view a series of thumbnails and click on them to view them in full size. I have managed to make this work but the way I have done it requires lots of repetitive code. Here is an example of what I have for each image:

**script**

```
function load1() {
    document.getElementById('wup').src = document.getElementById('wop1').src
            var myElement = document.querySelector("#wup");
            myElement.style.visibility = "visible";
            var myElementB = document.querySelector("button");
            myElementB.style.visibility = "visible";
            var myElementC = document.querySelector("#cover");
            myElementC.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
```

Pretty much what happens is every thumbnail (there are quite a lot) has one of these functions that runs when clicked. It makes a large image in the center of the screen appear, and the source of the image is whatever thumbnail was clicked. While this method does work, it requires lots of what feels like unnecessary repetition.

**What I am looking for:**

A simple and efficient way to do the same thing.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Functions do accept arguments, which means they can be reused with different parameters

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function that does this for each element.

```
function showLargeImage(thumbnail) {
  document.getElementById('wup').src = thumbnail.src
  document.querySelector("#wup").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.querySelector("button").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.querySelector("#cover").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Then for each image just call the function onclick.

```
<img id="wop" src="foo.jpg" onclick="showLargeImage(this)"/>
```